# How to make faster queries on my mysql table?

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have the following table
[image: I have the following table]

As you can see It has 1868155 rows. I am attempting to make a realtime graph, but It is impossible since almost any query lasts 1 or 2 seconds.

For example, this query

```
SELECT sensor.nombre, temperatura.temperatura
FROM sensor, temperatura
WHERE sensor.id = temperatura.idsensor
ORDER BY temperatura.fecha DESC, idsensor ASC
LIMIT 4
```

Is supposed to show this
[image]

Ive tried everything, using indexes(perhaps not correctly), using only the fields i need instead of *, etc. but the results are the same!

These are the indexes of the table.
[image: Indexes of the table]

Explain of the query
[image: Explain of the query]

EDITED
[image: EXPLAIN QUERY 2]
This is the explain of the query after implementing

```
ALTER TABLE temperatura
ADD INDEX `sensor_temp` (`idsensor`,`fecha`,`temperatura`)
```

And using inner join syntax for the query

```
SELECT s.nombre, t.temperatura
FROM sensor s
INNER JOIN temperatura t
ON s.id = t.idsensor
ORDER BY t.fecha DESC, t.idsensor ASC
LIMIT 4
```

This is my whole **sensor** table
[image: Sensor table]

Comment: The problem is probably that your indexing is not done correctly, but we can't tell without seeing the index definitions.  Please edit your question to show us how the tables were indexed.

Comment: Another thing to do is to prefix the query with Explain and add the output to your question. It will output the query plan and tell us what if any indexes it is going to use.

Comment: Please, go easy on the screenshots. 99% of the time they add almost zero value. They're not searchable, they can't be used by text-to-speech programs, and you can't easily copy and paste the content from them to develop solutions. Please use the results of  `SHOW CREATE TABLE` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to optimize a mixture of `ASC` and `DESC`, as in

```
ORDER BY t.fecha DESC, t.idsensor ASC
```

You tried a covering index:

```
INDEX `sensor_temp` (`idsensor`,`fecha`,`temperatura`)
```

However, this covering index may be better:

```
INDEX `sensor_temp` (`fecha`,`idsensor`,`temperatura`)
```

Then, if you are willing to get the sensors in a different order, use

```
ORDER BY t.fecha DESC, t.idsensor DESC
```

This will give you *up to* 4 sensors for the last `fecha`:

```
sensor: PRIMARY KEY(id)
tempuratura: INDEX(fecha, idsensor, tempuratura)

SELECT  
      ( SELECT  nombre FROM  sensor WHERE  id = t.idsensor ) AS nombre,
      t.temperatura
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  MAX(fecha) AS max_fecha FROM  tempuratura  ) AS z
    JOIN  temperatura AS t  ON t.fecha = z.max_fecha
    ORDER BY  t.idsensor ASC
    LIMIT  4;
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but will fail if ever the 4 sensors do not share the same timestamp (`fecha`). Or if a given sensor has the same timestamp twice. But if the data is guaranteed to always have all 4 sensors report for each `fecha` exactly once then this works.

Comment: Alas, I do not see a solution that is both fast and 'correct'.  A compromise:  First, run my query,  Check the output; if it has a flaw (less than 4, dups, etc), then run the original query.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
ALTER TABLE temperatura
ADD INDEX `sensor_temp` (`idsensor`,`fecha`,`temperatura`)
```

I also recommend using modern join syntax:

```
SELECT s.nombre, t.temperatura
FROM sensor s
INNER JOIN temperatura t
ON s.id = t.idsensor
ORDER BY t.fecha DESC, t.idsensor ASC
LIMIT 4
```

Report the EXPLAIN again after making the above changes, if performance is still not good enough.

## Attempt #2

After looking closely at what it appears you are trying to do, I believe this next query may be more effective:

```
SELECT
s.nombre, t.temperatura
FROM temperatura t
LEFT OUTER JOIN temperatura later_t
ON later_t.idsensor = t.idsensor
AND later_t.fecha > t.fecha
INNER JOIN sensor s
ON s.id = t.idsensor
WHERE later_t.idsensor IS NULL
ORDER BY t.idsensor ASC
```

You can also try:

```
SELECT
s.nombre, t.temperatura
FROM temperatura t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
    t.idsensor,
    MAX(t.fecha) AS fecha
    FROM temperatura t
    GROUP BY t.idsensor
) max_fecha
ON max_fecha.idsensor = t.idsensor
AND max_fecha.fecha > t.fecha
INNER JOIN sensor s
ON s.id = t.idsensor
ORDER BY t.idsensor ASC
```

In my experience, if you are trying to find the most recent record, one of the two queries above will work. Which works best depends on various factors, so try them both.

Let me know how those perform, and if they still get you the data you want. Also, any query you run, run at least 3 times, and report all 3 times. That will help get an accurate measure of how fast a given query is, since various external factors can affect the speed of a query.

Comment: @LucasRodríguez No, that's still horrible. I've updated my answer with a couple new queries to try.

Comment: What Im trying to do is get the temperature of the most recent records of each sensor (there are 4, that's why LIMIT 4), so in that way i can get the temperatures in realtime. I edited the question and put the sensor table, just in case.
The first query never finished so i had to restart the service. As for the second query: #1054 - Unknown column 'max_fecha.fecha' in 'on clause'. The version of Mysql Im using is 5.6.17

Comment: @LucasRodríguez Try the second query again, I corrected the mistake that was causing that error.

Comment: @LucasRodríguez Your explanation of what you are trying to do matches what I expected. Both queries I provided should get you that result. Since the first one was super slow, the second should work now that has the correct syntax. Note: you still need the index present at the start of my answer for these queries to work.